# What is the difference between "sip" and "drink" verbs?

Tags: meaning, speech

Title says it all. What is the difference? As I understand - "to sip" means the same as "to drink" but slowly. Are there any other aspects for choosing between them?

Comment: *sip* is to *drink* as *nibble* is to *eat*.

Answer (score 3):

"To sip" implies smaller amounts, whereas "To drink" implies average. (Something like "To gulp" would imply larger amounts)

Comment: Though _gulp_ is not limited to liquids, the way _sip_ and _drink_ are. Verbs and nouns for such common, intimate, essential, and variable human activities as eating, drinking, etc. **always** have loads of finely distinguished terms, sometimes related, usually metaphoric, often pejorative or obscene. In any culture. And they vary from place to place and group to group, even in the same language. Dictionaries are useless for talking about food when travelling; always there are new words to learn everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sipping is a particular  way of drinking. It means to drink little by little over a period of time while to drink is general.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Your definition is correct, but without references it is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: The OP might like to note that the difference can be medically important. I could swear I have seen directions on a bottle instructing me to "sip only".